# append a parameter to a command in the file and run the appended command

Tags: bash, nextflow

I have a the following command in a file called `$stat_val_result_command`.
I want to add  `-Xms1g` parameter at the end of the file so that is should look like this:

```
  <my command in the file> -Xms1g
```

However, I want to run this command after append. I am running this in a workflow system called "nextflow". I tied many things, including following, but it does not working. check the script section which runs in Bash by default:

````
    process statisticalValidation {

   input:
   file stat_val_result_command from validation_results_command.flatten()

   output:
   file "*_${params.ticket}_statistical_validation.txt" into validation_results

   script:
   """
   echo " -Xms1g"  >> $stat_val_result_command && ```cat  $stat_val_result_command```
   """
}
````

Comment: What's with the triple quotes? Bash treats three backticks _exactly the same_ as just one, except it's slower to execute, because it's one empty pair (open/close), then a pair with content in it, then another empty (open/close) pair. _All_ those pairs spawn subshells, including the empty ones.

Comment: Beyond that, `$(cat anything)` (or its backtick equivalent) has the bugs discussed in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), because the results of a command substitution are parsed the same way as the results of a parameter expansion.

Comment: If the file is in normal unix text file format, `echo " -Xms1g" >>thefile` will add a new line to the file, rather than adding to the line that's already there. This might not matter, due to the way you use the file, but I'd still check the file to see if that's what's happening.

Comment: @Gordan How can I add to the same line? How can I run it in bash after adding it?

Comment: Can you make the file a regular shell script, and pass `-Xms1g` to it as an argument (and have the script pass the argument on with e.g. `commandToRun "$@"`)?

Answer (score 1):

Best to avoid appending to or manipulating input files localized in the workdir as these can be, and are by default, symbolic links to the original files.

In your case, consider instead exporting the [JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#tooloptions) environment variable. This might or might not work for you, but might give you some ideas if you have control over how the scripts are being generated:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Xms1g"
bash "${stat_val_result_command}"
```

Also, it's generally better to avoid localizing and running scripts like this. It might be unavoidable, but usually there are better options. For example, [third-party scripts](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/sharing.html#third-party-scripts), like your Bash script could be handled more simply:

> Grant the execute permission to these files and copy them into a
> folder named `bin/` in the root directory of your project repository.
> Nextflow will automatically add this folder to the `PATH` environment
> variable, and the scripts will automatically be accessible in your
> pipeline without the need to specify an absolute path to invoke them.

This of course assumes you can control and parameterize the process that creates your Bash scripts.